# Pro trial not showing

Tags: install

Craft Personal 3.0.0-RC2 doesn't show the Pro Trial offer anymore? Is that correct?
I did install a Pro License however this triggers the system to change the domain (from local dev to live) which is unwanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing around trial usage has changed between Craft 2 and Craft 3, so as long as you follow this, it should work:

https://craftcms.com/support/try-craft-client-pro

Just keep in mind (because it sounds like you're swapping license keys around) that license.key info is cached for 24 hours at a time, so be sure and clear `craft/storage/runtime/cache` in whenever you do something like that to get accurate results and hit the updates page if you need to force a call home to Craft's web services.

Comment: Thank you, Brad - I had named the local site with an extension .blog - which caused the issue.